# How do I animate GIFs in Google Ads?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, google

I had this error when attempting to upload ads onto Google Ads.

> "We've detected strobing or Flashing effects. Make sure the frame rate of your ad is less than 5 FPS for GIFs. Learn more"

I followed the guidelines and requirements by making the animation with 0.2 fps and under 30 s in length.

Comment: related: https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

**It can be many things**

if the system is during uploads and if it is FPS related problem then first thing you should do is reduce frame rate little more via either photoshop or [Online Websites](https://ezgif.com/optimize) ; and still if they isn't letting you to upload your site you can always [ask support](https://support.google.com/google-ads/gethelp) for issues since they will provide you exact answer and issue .

Hope it helps to resolve your issues :)

Comment: Hi Design Phoenix, thank you for your response. I wasn't sure whether the FPS is the issue or the animation itself. It has 35 frames and I've set up each frame to 0.2 seconds (which means there are 5 frames per second). The animation's duration is 7 seconds total (35 frames divided by 5) and it can play 4 times (28 seconds)

Comment: if it saying less than 5 FPS how about setting it to 4+ :) in your case i just suggesting you to delete only 2 or 3 frames and it should works . and about flashing effects it seems they are talking about fire from your 2nd animation so first try uploading 1st image :)

Comment: I thought that Google will reject the fire animation. What you meant for the 35 frames that I have for the toaster animation, I should only delete 2 or 3 frames, so that gives a total of 32 or 33 frames? Sorry, I am a newbie on this

Comment: yeap that what i'm saying if they demand for 5 FPS animation go with something like 4 or so which is quite little and if they saying about flashy animation then avoid something in animation which catches your eyesight like fires etc XD

Comment: Hi Design Phoenix. Thank you so much for your help!